# Variance/covariance computations in a simple probability weighted estimator

Tags: probability, variance, covariance, bernoulli-distribution

My recent homework included a problem where I had to to show that:

$\frac{\delta^2}{p^2} Var(\hat{p}) - \frac{2 \delta}{p} Cov(\hat{\delta} + \frac{\delta}{p} (\hat{p} - p), \hat{p})$ < 0,

where $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i = 1} D_i$ and $\hat{\delta} = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i D_i}{\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} D_i} $. D is a dummy variable and $P(D=1) = p$. Also, it is known that $E[Y] = \delta$.

I should get that this expression simplifies to $-\frac{\delta^2 (1-p)}{np} < 0$.

I am suspecting that $Cov(\hat{\delta}, \hat{p})$ equals to zero, but I might be wrong.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with that problem.

Comment: Can you share what work you've done, and where exactly you get stuck?

Comment: Sure! In the next step, I simply expressed the covariance term and I got that the whole expression becomes $\frac{\delta^2}{p^2} Var(\hat{p}) - \frac{2 \delta}{p} Cov(\hat{\delta}, \hat{p}) - \frac{2 \delta^2}{p^2} Var(\hat{p})$. From here I get that: $ -\frac{\delta^2}{p^2} Var(\hat{p}) - \frac{2 \delta}{p} Cov(\hat{\delta}, \hat{p})$. And this is the point where I get stuck, because I am unable to calculate the covariance term:  $Cov(\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i D_i }{\sum^{n}_{i=1} D_i}, \sum^n_{j=1} D_j)$.

Comment: Sorry, here I should also have included $\frac{1}{n}$ in front of each sum inside the covariance term.

Comment: Focus individually on $Var(\hat{p})$ and $Cov(\hat{\delta},\hat{p})$. The first one may be fairly straightforward, and the second may seem to involve some annoying algebra, but you also know that $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$. What happens when you use that equation?

Comment: A further hint: covariance is bilinear,  as in $Cov(aX + bY, Z) = aCov(X,Z) + bCov(Y,Z)$. Maybe you can use that?

Comment: Thanks! So I managed to go some steps further. By using the bilinearity property, the covariance term can be written as $Cov(\hat{\delta}, \hat{p}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{j=1} Cov(\frac{Y_i D_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} D_i}, D_j)$ and because I have a random sample the covariances where $j \neq i$ are all equal to zero. Basically what remains is $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} Cov(\frac{Y_i D_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} D_i}, D_i) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} E[\frac{Y_i D^2_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} D_i}] - E[\frac{Y_i D_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} D_i}] E[D_i]$. I just only don't know what can I do with the sums in the denominator.

Comment: You write $\hat{\delta}$, suggesting that $E[\hat{\delta}] = \delta = E[Y]$. Why is that? Is $D_i$ independent of $Y_i$?